# Apostol: Axioms defining $1$ and $0$ and independence from $x$

Tags: proof-explanation, real-numbers

In Apostol's analysis textbook, two of the axioms he gives for the real numbers are:

> (Axiom 4) Given any two real numbers $x$ and $y$, there exists a real number $z$ such that $x + z = y$. This $z$ is denoted by $y - x$; the number $x - x$ is denoted by $0$. (**It can be proved that $0$ is independent of $x$.**) We write $- x$ for $0 - x$ and call $- x$ the negative of $x$.

> (Axiom 5) There exists at least one real number $x \neq 0$. If $x$ and $y$ are two real
> numbers with $x \neq 0$, then there exists a real number $z$ such that $xz = y$. This $z$ is denoted by $y/x$; t**he number $x/x$ is denoted by $1$ and can be shown to be independent of $x$.** We write $x^{-1}$ for $1/x$ if $x \neq 0$ and call $x^{-1}$ the reciprocal of $x$.

I don't understand the two statements in bold. It is certainly the case that for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $x - x = y - y = 0$, and it doesn't matter which $x$ or $y$ I use, and it's certainly the case that $\frac{x}{x} = \frac{y}{y} = 1$ for every $x,y \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and it doesn't matter which nonzero elements I pick. I don't know how to prove this, however.

Any help on how to approach this proof would be appreciated.

Comment: We can’t answer this question without knowing all the axioms. As it stands right now, we don’t even know that the notation $x - y$ is even well-defined, since we don’t know it’s unique. Also, do you mean Apostol?

Comment: This is approximately saying that "the additive identity, denoted $0$, is unique." Without any initial notions, we might imagine that there could be multiple numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$, say, that both satisfy $z_1 + x = x$ and $z_2 +x = x$ for all $x$. But it turns out that there is precisely one such real number, and it's denoted $0$.

Comment: @davidlowryduda The issue is that as far as I can tell, you cannot prove $x - x$ is an identity at all from this axiom. You would need uniqueness in axiom 4 to prove this.

Comment: one way of thinking about this is to note that the bold statements are a question of proving that the definitions of $0$ and $1$ which are given are good definitions - that they don't depend on the choice of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

For context, the other axioms here are the associativity and commutativity of $+$ and $\cdot$ and the distributive property.

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to prove the two facts laid out from the axioms. There are three conditions which, assuming only associativity and commutativity of $+$ and axiom 4, are equivalent.

> Claim 1: For all $x, y, z$, if $x + y = x + z$ then $y = z$

> Claim 2: For all $x, y$, there is a unique $z$ such that $x + z = y$.

> Claim 3: If there is any $x$, then there is an additive identity $0$ such that for all $y$, $y + 0 = y$.

> Claim 4: There is some binary operation $-$ such that for all $x, y$, we have $x + (y - x) = y$ and also $x - x = y - y$.

> Claim 5: There is some binary operation $-$ such that for all $x, y$, we have $x + (y - x) = y$ and $(x + y) - x = y$.

Proof:

For $1 \to 2$, we know there is some $z$ such that $x + z = y$. If we had $w$ such that $x + z = x + w$, then we could cancel the $x$ to get $z = w$.

For $2 \to 3$, consider some $x$. Take the unique $0$ such that $x + 0 = x$. Now consider some $y$. Note that $x + (y + 0) = y + (x + 0) = y + x = x + y$. Thus, both $y + 0$ and $y$ are the unique $z$ such that $x + z = x + y$; therefore, $y + 0 = y$.

For $3 \to 1$, suppose that $x + z = x + w$. Take some additive identity $0$, and take some $q$ such that $x + q = 0$. Then we have $q + x + z = q + x + w$, so $w = z$. We see that 1, 2, 3 are all equivalent.

For $4 \to 3$, the additive identity in question is $x - x$. We have $(x - x) + y = (y - y) + y = y$.

Conversely, for $1, 2, 3 \to 4$, let $y - x$ be the unique $z$ such that $x + z = y$. The fact that $x + (y - x) = y$ follows from the distance. The fact that $x - x = y - y$ follows from the fact that both of these are necessarily the additive identity $0$.

I’ll leave showing the equivalence of 5 as an exercise.

The situation is of course quite similar with $\cdot$, which also satisfies the associative and commutative laws.